# c++ virtual class function returning instance of concrete subclass

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

What I would like, if not with this syntax, but in spirit :

```
class A
{
   virtual A f()=0;
};

class B : public A
{
   B f();
};
```

I do see the problem with the code above : A is virtual, thus no instance of A can be created, hence no instance of A can be returned.

Yet, concrete subclasses of A (e.g. B) will have to implement the function f, which will always be able to return an instance of themselve (e.g. instance of B), i.e. an instance of a subclass of A.

While the above is incorrect and does not compile, is there a way to get something similar valid ?
Possibly, but not necessarily, of the like:

```
class A 
{
   virtual "a concrete sublclass of A" f()=0;
};
```

note: I prefer not to return a pointer or a reference, as I would prefer B not to have to manage an instance of itself as attribute.

note: if possible c++11, but curious to hear about newer versions as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempted solution risks object slicing. Copying a `B` as an `A` will probably not work the way you expect. In general, it's best to avoid value semantics when dealing with polymorphic types. Consider returning a `std::unique_ptr<A>` instead :

```
#include <memory>
class A
{
public:
   virtual std::unique_ptr<A> f()=0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
   std::unique_ptr<A> f() override;
};
```

This requires C++11. It will behave the way you expect and the user won't have to manage the lifetime of the resulting object.

However, contrary to what was shown in the original code, `B::foo()` won't give you access to the full interface of a `B`. It's not clear to me if this is required or not. If it is, you will need an extra layer. For example, define a `g()` that returns `std::unique_ptr<B>` which `f()` calls :

```
class B : public A
{
public:
   std::unique_ptr<A> f() override { return g(); }
   std::unique_ptr<B> g();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to write a factory or clone function of sorts. This is commonly done using `std::unique_ptr` to cleanly pass ownership of the created object to the caller:

```
class A
{
   virtual std::unique_ptr<A> f() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
   std::unique_ptr<A> f() override;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/srzVdf)

The only downside is that you cannot have `B::f` return a `std::unique_ptr<B>` as that's not covariant with `std::unique_ptr<A>` (even though it implicitly converts to it).

Comment: You can still play with covariant `A*` and non-covariant `std::unique_ptr<A>` to have expected interface (possibly with CRTP).

Answer (score 1):

> note: if possible c++11, but curious to hear about newer versions as well

No. that is not possible. You can return a covariant type in a derived class though.

If the return type in the base classs is `A&`, it is ok to return `B&` in `B`.
If the return type in the base classs is `A*`, it is ok to return `B*` in `B`.

```
class A
{
   virtual A& f()=0;
   virtual A* g()=0;
};

class B : public A
{
   B& f();
   B* g()=0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Write something like

```
class A
{
   virtual const A& f() const = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
   const B& f() const override { return *this; }
};
```

Instead of reference you may use pointers.